# Excel is saying zero is not equal to zero (CLOSED)

Tags: excel

I have two formulas one that works and one that doesn't.

The following formula works.

```
M28 cell value = 1192481.00
M28 cell formula = =SUM(M6:M27)
=IF(M28=1192481,TRUE,FALSE).
```

This accurately returns TRUE as 1192481.00 is equal to 1192481.

The following however does not work.

```
N28 cell value = 0
N28 cell formula = =SUM(N6:N27)
=IF(N28=0,TRUE,FALSE).
```

This returns FALSE.

When I evaluate the formula in Excel (Formulas tab -> 'Evaluate Formula' button).  It shows N28's value as -8.00355337560177E-11.  Why is this happening and how do I fix this.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is wrong with the question why is it negative?

Comment: What formula is in `N28`?

Comment: added that info.

Comment: N28 is **not** zero; it the result of a formula that suffers from excel's floating point error and the raw result is close to zero but not zero (e.g. -0.00000000008003). Look up excel floating point error on the internet.

Comment: Then obviously `=SUM(N6:N27)` is not exactly `0`. So what values are in `N6:N27` and where they are coming from? But as the simplest solution you could using rounding.  `=ROUND(SUM(N6:N27),5)` for example to round to 5 decimal places.

Comment: Jeeped and Axel Richter answer the question below and I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jeeped and Axel Richter already answered in the comment section below the question.

It is a floating point error.  Increase the decimals for your value and you can clearly see it.